# Getting all public basic profile information from Linkedin API

Tags: rest, linkedin-api

I am looking for a way to get all public profile information from linkedin API just in the same way one would see it in the public linkedin directory:

https://www.linkedin.com/directory/people-a/

[image]

Is this possible? with or without authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current [linkedin api](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api) I think only works for its own profile. There's not an API for retrieve information of the other profiles, you'll need write your own scraper

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly the same as the directory. But with the list of public profiles you can get the the details from the below API.

https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/url=URLENCODED_PUBLIC_PROFILE_URL?format=json

**Example:**

https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com%2Fin%2Farunkumar-krishnan-02536015?format=json

will fetch my user profile in json format. One can build a directory of known users from this.

Hope it helps!