# Retrieving public profile information from LinkedIn API

Tags: linkedin-api

What I want to do is to use the LinkedIn Search API (I know it's part of a Partner Program) to search for (public) profiles by name.

Afterwards, (If not already retrieved from the Search API, which I don't know because I don't have access to the documentation which is part of the Partner Program which I haven't applied for yet), I want to use the IDs of the result to get (full) information via the [LinkedIn Profile API](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/people/profile-api).

My question is if it's possible to retrieve information of other LinkedIn profiles (profiles I haven't connected with on my LinkedIn profile) while just authenticating with my own account/profile?

---

In the *Retrieve Other Member's Profile* section of the [Profile-API-Doc](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/people/profile-api) it seems like it's possible if you have the ID.

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32233776/getting-all-public-basic-profile-information-from-linkedin-api) on the other hand the answer of *rkmax* states it's not possible.

---

I've already done some research but all this different information is confusing me. I'd really appreciate any help!